# URL Not loading in a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm using a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control to load a webpage. My understanding is it is just a wrapper around Internet Explorer. I'm therefore struggling to understand why the web page loads ok in a desktop browser (IE 11) but not in the browser control.

The URL has looks as so:

http://subdomain.domain.co.uk/?argumentName=argumentValue

My question is, firstly, is that a valid url (format wise)? Can you have a '?' directly after the '/' as shown? My theory is this could be getting removed behind the scenes when using a desktop browser and not happening when using the browser control. Unfortunately I cannot test that theory as the web page is behind a firewall. At the moment I know nothing else about the location of the web page other than the url.

If that is a valid url, could anyone suggest reasons it would load in IE but not in the web browswer control?

To expand on how its not working, the request times out after 30 seconds. The NavigateError event is raised (status code for me is -2146697211, but that could well be different to status code they get. I cannot find that out until I deploy a dll with some logging info).

The webpage then displays as

[image: The Navigation Error shown]

Comment: The URL is fine. But you will have to expand on what you mean by it not working in the browser control. How is it not working? (throwing an exception, showing an error on the page, etc.)

Comment: In addition, listing how all of the WebBrowser's properties are set would probably help also. A simple screen clipping of the properties pane should be good enough.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming at all? If an URL is valid is a pure networking-related question.